# Comment se nomme précisément cet objet ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, littérature

Peut-on étayer comment se nomme précisément cet objet en métal essentiellement constitué d'une caisse sur roues, que j'ai vu dans mon enfance et dans des films, et qui est souvent mu par des enfants ? Le haut du manche qu'on ne voit pas dans l'image est muni d'une poignée moulée à même le métal. Connaît-on en passant une oeuvre (littérature) où l'on en parle ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Un petit chariot métallique pour enfant.

> Un chariot à tirer.

J'ai demandé à mes enfants comme ils appelaient la chose et les deux m'ont répondu:

> Une chariotte.

Ils ne sont pas les seuls car j'ai trouvé [une page](http://www.garage-cormier.fr/page/chariotte-de-jardin) où *chariotte* est utilisé pour un objet très similaire :

[image]

Une autre [ici](https://www.lairdubois.fr/creations/10253-chariotte-et-menagerie.html).

Ce mot d'ancien français équivalent à *charette* (deux roues) à été remis au goût du jour avec le film *Les Visiteurs* (1993) dans lequel il désigne une automobile (*Une chariotte du diable, tout est ferré, il n'y a point de bœuf pour tirer*). Les occurrences modernes désignant des remorques à deux roues sont cependant bien plus nombreuses.

Comment: Il y a un modèle en bois avec un dossier et parfois on trouve « traîneau sur roue(s) » mais c'est assez rare. J'ai aussi vu _chariot-traîneau_ avec un modèle aux caractéristiques amphibies disons. Dans d'autres rares cas la même cooccurence mais c'est du SEO. De prime abord ça pourrait laisser croire que le traîneau vaut pour _à tirer_ d'une certaine manière mais non, c'est vraiment le [_chariot_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chariot), l'exemple c'est vraiment la quadrature du cercle : _Gosses qui jouent à se traîner dans un chariot_ (Renard, Journal,1905, p. 977) ; il est là le traîneau !

Comment: Ce serait à cause de la corde ?!

Comment: J'avais mal lu ton commentaire, je pensais que tu disais qu'il était en bois. On appelle pas (ou plus) ça un traîneau ici car c'est limité à ce qui n'a pas de roue mais des patins, comme le traîneau du Père-Noël...

Comment: Merci, intéressant, oui au [Godefroy](https://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/chariot). Dans _Les Visiteurs_ c'est vraiment loufoque parce que la langue que Reno utilise, qui est archaïque et rétrograde, je la trouve vraiment émouvante, expressive et noble. Je trouve le film émouvant comme un truc historique ahahahah, c'est une comédie à plus d'un titre. _Chariotte_ est vraiment plaisant, comme _fillotte_...